# jQuery Context Selector Discrepancy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The challenge is to add a specific class to a specific button in a jQuery UI Dialog Box.

I have tested both of these and this will work:

```
$('button:contains("Add New")', $('#selectDialog').parent()).addClass('alternateButtonStyle');
```

This; however, will not work:

```
$('button:contains("Add New")', '#selectDialog:parent').addClass('alternateButtonStyle');
```

Why won't the second code sample work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `:parent` selector does not select the parent element, it just filters to elements that are a parent. It is the inverse of `:empty`.

http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

It won't work because it doesn't do what you think it does.

That use-case is also undocumented, your context selector should actually be a jquery object, just wrap it in `$()`

Undocumented functionality is likely to be broken without warning.

Comment: I see; good point.  Is there a way to use a selector as opposed to calling the jQuery `$` method like I did?

Comment: @user1477388 No. Why do you want to use a selector?

Comment: I feel it should be faster as it is less text.

Comment: I would expect `$('#selectDialog').parent()` to be faster, but which one is faster doesn't matter in this case because the difference will be negligible.

Comment: True, it's negligible; however, I was curious as to why it didn't work.  Perhaps, they should rename `:parent` to `:isParent` as that seems more appropriate based on your response.

Comment: @user, it doesn't work because the context must be either a jQuery object or a DOM element. Selectors strings are not supported.

Comment: It did work in all versions of jQuery prior to 2.0.0b3 (it does in 2.0 edge). In either case, it's undocumented and should be wrapped in `$()`

Comment: @Kevin, interesting, IIRC the documentation never mentioned strings being supported. It might have been an accidental feature :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am using 1.9.1 and I can do this successfully `$('.dob', '#updateAdjusterDialog').datepicker();` (no object, just string)

Comment: Yeah, i never noticed that it wasn't documented, it just has always worked for me. :p

Comment: @user1477388 Why should `:parent` be renamed to `:isParent`? All of the pseudo (`:foo`) selectors have a semantic meaning of `:isFoo`. That's what they're meant for. `:checked` means "is checked", `:text` means "is a textbox"